# WSO2 EI - Performance Issues for Iterate mediator with a huge number of nodes

Tags: integration, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Is there any performance implication on using the iterate mediator with very huge list of nodes? More than 1000 nodes like below:

```
<parent>
  <child>
    <a></a>
  </child>
  <!-- N Child Nodes -->

</parent>
```

For each child node we need to perform some validation steps and invoke a WS.

The first implication I see is the number of threads it is going to create this can be a problem depending on the number of nodes that will be iterated over.

In case this is an issue, Is there any suggestion on how to deal with this kind of scenario on WSO2 EI?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It can iterate very fast. Are you sure third party webservice will be able to handle such huge amount of requests?

Comment: I prefer to use for each mediator to split and save each message in store. Then sampling message processor get every several second on message and send it.

Comment: @simar the third party web service will be able to handle the load. This process is a batch process, and thoses are data from a CSV file read using Smooks Mediator. I liked the idea of using a Store/Processor, the problem would be on how to know that the process is completed. Do you have any suggestion when it comes to batch processing on WSo2 EI?

Comment: I Have made a test with a XML with 1000 nodes and iterate mediator throws an exception:

Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Maximum Element Depth Exceeded

I'll try to find another way of doing that.

Comment: Iterate split original message and create new small message. Each small message has own life(own thread to process it. I am not sure but default number of threads in ESB 500, and maximum around 5000.

Comment: @simar I had another try and I am being able to iterate over a huge file, it is not very fast, but it is working also I needed to tune the threads on synapse.properties. Thanks for your help!